# A question on diophantine equations.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, diophantine-equations

Looking at an old exam paper I cam across a question which goes as follows :

1) Show that the continued fraction of $\sqrt{14}=[3;\overline{1,2,16}]$.

2)hence or otherwise obtain 3 solutions to $x^2-14y^2=1$

3) Determine all $a,b \in \Bbb Z$ satisfying the Diophantine equation $ax^2_ 0 + by^2_ 0 = 1$ for $(x_0,y_0)$ as in (2)

4) Let $(xi,yi)$ be the $i^{th}$ solution to the Diophantine equation in part (2). Explain why solutions $a,b \in \Bbb Z$ always exist to the Diophantine equation $ax^2 _i +by^2_i = 1.$

1) and 2) are trivial but 3 and 4 have me quite stumped I looked back at my old notes and I couldn't find anything  about it. Could anyone provide method of proof for 3) and an explanation for 4) ?

Note: I only want to use elementary techniques of number theory as I'm only just learning it, and doing so in the context of number theory .

Comment: What is part (d) in your item (4)? Without knowing what your questions exactly are, I guess the reason for (4) is that the $(x,y)$ solutions in Pell's equations are relatively prime.

Comment: @HwChu sorry that was meant to be a (2)

Answer (score 0):

HINT.

►The fondamental unit of the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{14})$ is easily find (besides of the continued fraction)  with the first $b^2$ such that $14b^2$ be an square minus $1$ so we determine from $14\times(4^2)=15^2-1$ that all the solutions of $x^2-14y^2=1$ are given by
$$a_n+b_n\sqrt{14}=(15+4\sqrt{14})^n$$
►If $x_i^2-14y_i^2=1$ and we want to solve $ax_i^2+by_i^2=1$ (**where the unknowns are $a$ and $b$**) it is clear that $(a,b)=(1,-14)$ is a solution. And it is quite known the parameterization of all the solutions (infinitely many) of a linear equation when we have a particular solution.

Comment: Is there a way to do it just using elementary number theory ? you're answer went a bit over my head ...

Comment: Be the equation $ax+by=c$ and $x_0,y_0$ a solution. You do have $$ax+by=c\\ax_0+by_0=c$$ Then
$$a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)=0$$ Put $x-x_0=bt$ and $y-y_0=-at$ so you have $abt-abt=0$. You get this way all the solutions
$$x=bt+x_0\\y=-at+y_0$$